# Negative Rotation Speed (vsini)

Tags: star

I've repeatedly seen the [rotation speed of a star given as a negative](http://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/sim-id?mescat.diameter=on&mescat.distance=on&mescat.rot=on&mescat.fe_h=on&Ident=%402625287&Name=HD%20165222&submit=display%20selected%20measurements#lab_meas). Does this mean that the star started spinning in the opposite direction at some point?

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me.